# preg_match phone numbers with removal

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I'm trying to check if a string contains a phone number. There are several phone number formats. See list below. I was trying to add them to preg_match check after which they can be removed from the string.

```
06-12341234 - [0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{8}
0612341234 - [0-9]{10}
+31 6 12341234 
31612341234
0031 6 12341234 - [0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{1}[\s][0-9]{8}
+31612341234
0031612341234 - [0-9]{11}
06 1234 1234 - [0-9]{2}[\s][0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{4}
06-1234 1234 - [0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{4}
```

and many more. But isn't there a better check to find phone numbers and replace them? The snippet below doesn't strip the phone numbers from the string.

```
if(preg_match('/
        [0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{8}| 
        [0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{1}[\s][0-9]{8}|
        [0-9]{10}|
        [0-9]{11}|
        /', $Message)){
    //URLS
    $pattern = "/
        [0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{8}| 
        [0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{1}[\s][0-9]{8}|
        [0-9]{10}|
        [0-9]{11}|
        /";
    $replacement = "[removed]";
    $Message = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    $Score = $Score+20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the right approach to use preg_replace(), but you don't have to check with preg_match() first. You can just check whether the string is the same afterwards or not. If it's not the same, you would do the other stuff you need, like incrementing the score.

So your code would look like this:

```
$replacement = "[removed]";
$message = preg_replace('/(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?/', $replacement, $string);
if ($message != $replacement) {
    $score = $score + 20;
}
```

Note: I found the pattern above for matching phone numbers, I'm not sure if it works for your data, you should test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the letter `x` to the end of your pattern(s):

Instead of this:

```
$pattern = '/
        [0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{8}| 
        [0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{1}[\s][0-9]{8}|
        [0-9]{10}|
        [0-9]{11}|
        /';
```

Use this:

```
$pattern = '/
        [0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{8}| 
        [0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{1}[\s][0-9]{8}|
        [0-9]{10}|
        [0-9]{11}|
        /x';
```

Better yet, define the pattern once and reuse it:

```
// If the pattern is the same, there's no point in writing it twice.
// Save some time and possibly prevent errors by using the same pattern
// in each check.
$pattern = '/
        [0-9]{2}[\-][0-9]{8}| 
        [0-9]{4}[\s][0-9]{1}[\s][0-9]{8}|
        [0-9]{10}|
        [0-9]{11}|
        /x';
if (preg_match($pattern, $Message)) {
    //URLS
    $replacement = "[removed]";
    $Message = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    $Score = $Score+20;
}
```

Comment: hi, just tested your changes. However, it removes the entire string and not a part of it. What should I change to remove only the phone number?

Comment: Well I don't see `$string` defined anywhere so I'm not sure where that comes from... Are you trying to produce an array of matches out of `preg_match()`? Or which part are you trying to replace?